# Variable destructuring assignment after declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, destructuring

First of all I carefully read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and checked similar StackOverflow questions. I have a sequence of SQL requests. When I write this, everything works fine:

```
  const { rows } = await db.query(`
    SELECT *  FROM table
    WHERE id = ${id}`)
```

But I'd like to make several requests, that's why I thought about writing this:

```
  let rows;

  { rows } = await db.query(`
    SELECT *  FROM table
    WHERE id = ${id}`)

  // do something with the rows

  { rows } = await db.query(`
    SELECT *  FROM othertable
    WHERE id = ${id}`)

  // do something else
```

But I have this error:

```
  { rows } = await db.query(`
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
```

Seeing the documentation, it appears to be a simple assignment, I don't know what is wrong with this. Any help would be very kind :)

Comment: Also, as an alternative to destructuring `rows = (await db.query(/* ... */)).rows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`({rows} = await db.query(...))`

you should use parenthesis to signal it's not a block but an assignment